Pagination Laravel VueTailwindPagination
i cant undesrtand why when i use the tag for the pagination , i cant retreive anything...
In the controller:
$departments = Department::select('name')->paginate(5);


return Inertia::render('Departments/Index',['departments' => $departments]);

and in the view:
const props = defineProps({
departments: {type:Object}});
const form = useForm({  id:'',name:''});
const formPage = useForm({});
const onPageClick = (event)=>{
formPage.get(route('departments.index',{page:event}));



 
                    </td>
                    <td class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-4">
                        <DangerButton @click="deleteDepartment(dep.id,dep.name)">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                        </DangerButton>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                           </div>

            <VueTailwindPagination
                :current="departments.currentPage" :total="departments.total"
                :per-page="departments.perPage"
                @page-changed="$event => onPageClick($event)"
            ></VueTailwindPagination>
        </div>
      
    </div>

ok then if i use in the controller  $departments =   $departments = Department::all(); i can see in the view all the data but dont with pagination.
Thanks in advance.

In your vue prop, the data you are looking for will be located @ departments.data.
When using the paginate() function Laravel, the results will be structured like this (represented in Json below):
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Record...
        },
        {
            // Record...
        }
   ]
}

Example taken from the docs here.
Assuming you are trying to loop through the results, you would do something like this in your vue file:
<template v-for="department in departments.data"
</template

